# How can I get child objects inside parent object using Python and SQL?

Tags: python, sql, api, flask

I'm trying to create a basic API and I have one table called orders and another called order_lines which has a row for each product ordered with a field called order_id that corresponds back to orders. When doing a GET request how can I have the order as a parent and each order_lines record within it as a child array? I'm not sure if I need to do this in SQL somehow or if I can easily do it in Python. I just need a general idea how to pull and construct this data.

My API GET request looks like this:

```py
@app.route('/api/v1/ordertest', methods=['GET'])
def orders_test2():
    # try:
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query_parameters = request.args

        id = query_parameters.get('id')
        customer_id = query_parameters.get('customer_id')

        query = '''
                    SELECT 
                        o.*,
                        ol.product_id, 
                        p.name, 
                        ol.quantity, 
                        p.price as price, 
                        round((p.price * ol.quantity), 2) as total_price
                    FROM orders o
                    join order_lines ol
                    on o.id = ol.order_id
                    join products p
                    on ol.product_id = p.id
                    WHERE o.
                '''
        to_filter = []

        if id:
            query += 'id=? AND'
            to_filter.append(id)
        if customer_id:
            query += 'customer_id=? AND'
            to_filter.append(customer_id)

        if not (id or customer_id):
            return page_not_found(404)

        query = query[:-4] + ';'

        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        conn.row_factory = dict_factory
        cur = conn.cursor()

        results = cur.execute(query, to_filter).fetchall()

        return jsonify(results)
```

Doing `/api/v1/ordertest?id=1` returns all the data I want, but it has the information from the orders table listed in the object for each product.

```json
[
  {
    "created_at": "2020-11-12 00:08:32", 
    "customer_id": 1, 
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "plum", 
    "price": 0.3, 
    "product_id": 4, 
    "quantity": 2, 
    "status": "delivered", 
    "total_price": 0.6, 
    "updated_at": "2021-02-05 18:41:20"
  }, 
  {
    "created_at": "2020-11-12 00:08:32", 
    "customer_id": 1, 
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "salmon", 
    "price": 6.76, 
    "product_id": 20, 
    "quantity": 4, 
    "status": "delivered", 
    "total_price": 27.04, 
    "updated_at": "2021-02-05 18:41:20"
  }, 
  {
    "created_at": "2020-11-12 00:08:32", 
    "customer_id": 1, 
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "mint chocolate bar", 
    "price": 2.01, 
    "product_id": 30, 
    "quantity": 3, 
    "status": "delivered", 
    "total_price": 6.03, 
    "updated_at": "2021-02-05 18:41:20"
  }
]
```

However, I want the data to look something like this where each order_lines row with the matching order_id lives inside the main object:

```json
[
    {
      "created_at": "2020-11-12 00:08:32", 
      "customer_id": 1, 
      "id": 1, 
      "status": "delivered", 
      "updated_at": "2021-02-05 18:41:20",
      "products": 
      {
          "name": "plum", 
          "price": 0.3, 
          "product_id": 4, 
          "quantity": 2,
          "total_price": 0.6
          }, 
      {
          "name": "salmon", 
          "price": 6.76, 
          "product_id": 20, 
          "quantity": 4, 
          "total_price": 27.04
      }, 
      {
          "name": "mint chocolate bar", 
          "price": 2.01, 
          "product_id": 30, 
          "quantity": 3, 
          "total_price": 6.03
        }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Consider using an ORM like [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

Comment: In production you usually write out each column name (instead of using *) as it serves for documentation and it ensures that code doesn't change behavior just because a new column is added to a table you use.  If you use the name same for the primary and secondary key, you can use natural joints which means you don't need to specify all the boiler plate joint conditions.  I.e. instead of orders.id use orders.order_id as your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Managing a database, should be through SQL management system such as MySQL , SQLite... you can use them by importing their python libraries into your code to perform SQL queries.
your problem can be solved using :

```
    SELECT column_name(s)
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I do have it set up like this in my database, but when performing such a join it returns the data from table 1 on each row of table 2's data which isn't ideal. I am just wanting to have the data from table 1 show once at the top and then list each row from table 2 below it as children

Comment: In this case you can use SELECT UNION.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up on REST(ful) APIs as it will give you an idea of how to handle hierarchical data (GraphQL would be another way). You can have two end-points, as you mentioned, or a single end-point:

```
GET /orders?order_id=1 or
GET /orders/1
```

which might be return something like this (csv, json would be also be a good choice but adds more noise to the example):

```
item,quantity,price
Bicycle,1,$500
Helmet,1,$125
```

If you want to use two end-points, it could instead return links to each order item:

```
/order_line/27
/order_line/42
```

Anther design choice would be to encode the hierarchy of your data in the URL like this:

```
 /order/1/order_line/27
 /order/1/order_line/42
```

Then your client get each of these URLs to
extract additional information.  It would have have a large overhead, so you usually embed the data in a single end-point for small data like this.

When you write the code you would extract the order_id in this 1, and get the values your database in this SQL might be:

```
select item, quantity, price from line_items where order_id = 1
```

(make sure you bind variables with whatever database API you decide to use).  The relevant tables might look something like this:

```
create table orders (
   order_id int primary key,
);

create table order_lines (
   order_line_id int primary key,
   order_id int not null references orders (order_id),
);
```

Comment: Hi, in your example I am getting every row of order_lines for the corresponding id, but I wouldn't be getting the information from orders as well. I want the orders data to be a parent and then each row of order_lines associated to live inside it as a child object. I have updated my question with my code and JSON for better context

Comment: There no magic, Cole, you write a function that converts the data from the database into the format you require.   Your results variable will have a row per line item, this means you can get the order detail from the first row `order = [ 'created_at': results[0]['created_at'], ...].  orders[0]['products'] is your line items, so you can generate those with a list comprehension.